Why are the tables not displaying side by side?
I'm attempting to format a report and am running into annoying issues with the formatting. What I'm trying to do is display these tables side by side, but each seems to really want to appear on a new line. I'd also like to keep the formatting such that it can be knit to a PDF.
```{r OWNER TABLE, echo = F}
owner_probs <- data.frame(In = c(0.56, 0.24), 
                          Out = c(0.14, 0.06))
row.names(owner_probs) <- c("In", "Out")

owner_dse <- owner_probs * 350000

owner_probs <- owner_probs %>%
  kable(longtable = T,
        booktabs = T, 
        align = "c", 
        caption = "Probability Table") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "bordered",
                position = "float_left") %>% 
  column_spec (1:3,
               border_left = T, 
               border_right = T)

owner_dse <- owner_dse %>%
  kable(longtable = T,
        booktabs = T, 
        align = "c", 
        caption = "DSE Table") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "bordered",
                position = "float_right") %>% 
  column_spec (1:3,
               border_left = T,
               border_right = T)

owner_probs
owner_dse
```

PDF Image
Edit: I believe these are the tex lines for the tables,
\subsection{Owner (On a Population of
350,000)}\label{owner-on-a-population-of-350000}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {|>{}l||>{}c||>{}c|}
\caption{\label{tab:OWNER TABLE}Probability Table}\\
\toprule
 & In & Out\\
\midrule
In & 0.56 & 0.14\\
Out & 0.24 & 0.06\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtabu}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {|>{}l||>{}c||>{}c|}
\caption{\label{tab:OWNER TABLE}DSE Table}\\
\toprule
 & In & Out\\
\midrule
In & 196000 & 49000\\
Out & 84000 & 21000\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtabu}


Can you show the intermediate .tex file?

just added the lines for the two tables

oh, they really still use tabu? That's more or less completely broken

How easy would it be to convert from tabu to a different method? I could potentially just rewrite the latex for the tables after knitting

If you are willing to edit the tex code, the minimal invasive way to get the tables besides each other would be minipages around them: https://pastebin.com/4fEZv7rz . Note that this is far from good code. It would be better to use a tabular and combining the booktabs package with vertical lines is the tex equivalent of a mortal sin.

Ah gotcha, I appreciate the reply! I will use this and edit the tex file! I will make sure I repent for my sins and remove the booktabs :P

No, don't remove booktabs! Remove the vertical lines!

@Miller25: They aren't side-by-side because there's an empty line between the two tables in the code.
